# Unable to install sandwich package: installation of package ‘sandwich’ had non-zero exit status

Tags: r, install.packages, plm

I need to install the "plm" package. After installing it, the "sandwich" package was missing.

```
> library(plm)
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘plm’ in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]):
 there is no package called ‘sandwich
```

Tried to install the "sandwich" package, returned with this:

```
Installing package into ‘library_path’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
also installing the dependency ‘zoo’

There is a binary version available but the source version is later:
         binary source needs_compilation
sandwich  2.3-4  2.4-0             FALSE

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.4/zoo_1.8-0.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 901864 bytes (880 KB)
downloaded 880 KB

package ‘zoo’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked

The downloaded binary packages are in
    C:\directory\downloaded_packages
installing the source package ‘sandwich’

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/sandwich_2.4-0.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 1280592 bytes (1.2 MB)
downloaded 1.2 MB

'\\directory\My Documents'
CMD.EXE was started with the above path as the current directory.
UNC paths are not supported.  Defaulting to Windows directory.
* installing *source* package 'sandwich' ...
** package 'sandwich' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** R
** data
** inst
** preparing package for lazy loading
** help
*** installing help indices
** building package indices
** installing vignettes
Warning in file(con, "w") :
  cannot open file '\\library_path/sandwich/doc/index.html': No such file or directory
Error in file(con, "w") : cannot open the connection
ERROR: installing vignettes failed
* removing '\\library_path/sandwich'
Warning in install.packages :
  running command '"C:/R-34~1.1/bin/x64/R" CMD INSTALL -l "\\library_path" C:\directory/downloaded_packages/sandwich_2.4-0.tar.gz' had status 1
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘sandwich’ had non-zero exit status

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘C:\directory\downloaded_packages’
```

Had tried:

1. Reinstall R and RStudio directly to C (not in C:\Program Files)
2. Using this command to install all the dependencies:

   `install.packages("sandwich", dependencies=TRUE)`

Still, the "non-zero exit status" appeared. Do you have any suggestions?

I am using Windows 7 (64 bit), R 3.4.1 and RStudio 1.0.153

Comment: tried type = "source" or removing the library folder manually before fresh install?

Comment: resulting the same error :(

even now the "zoo" package displayed "non-zero exit"

Comment: what is the output of `.libPaths()` ? I suspect RStudio did not detect `C:\directory\downloaded_packages` as a library location

Comment: Hi @hongsy it is recognized the folder "C:/R-3.4.1/library"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think i found a temporary answer for my problem. I previously had problems related to the privilege in writing the library folder in R. Tried to work around by turning off anti-virus live update, change the security of the R folder, etc. I thought it was worked, since I did not find anymore issues on "unable to move temporary installation....". But when I restart my computer, the problem came again.

Since I am working in a university provided laptop, I need to wait until the IT grants me access as an admin. While waiting for it, I created a new library in C:/ (in my case, I named it as "R library local"). Downloaded all the package to that library

install.packages("plm", dependencies = TRUE, lib = "C:/R library local")

And load the package from the library

library("plm", lib="C:/R library local")

It works well :)

Dunno if I still need the admin access for the library in R folder or not.

Comment: yes, it does seem that access rights are causing your installation problems, especially since it's a university-issued laptop. I would suggest renaming your library as "C:/R-library-local" (i.e. without spacing) to prevent any compilation problems.

Comment: Do mark your question as answered by checking the tick to the left of the answer.

Comment: Thanks, @hongsy :)